# How do I find intersection of 3 arrays, while ignoring empty arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to find intersection elements of 3 integer arrays
say a, b, c with a condition; if any of the array is null ( `[]` ),
simply ignore the array and find intersection of the remaining arrays,
and if all three are null, then return [].
Thanks in advance.

ps:Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Can you post some example arrays and expected results?

Comment: a=[]
b=[1,2]
c=[2]
result=[2]

Comment: @tokland 
something weird :P
`
i=-1
i+=1 if a.present?
i+=1 if b.present?
i+=1 if c.present?
res=(a+b+c)
res.select{|e| res.count(e)>i }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it would be this:

```
[ a, b, c ].tap{ |a| a.delete( [] ) }.reduce( :& ) || []
```

Other options suggested in the discussion are:

```
[ a, b, c ].reject( &:empty? ).reduce( :& ) || []
```

and:

```
[ a, b, c ].select( &:any? ).reduce( :& ) || []
```

But in this last case, beware of non-empty arrays with explicit nil elements, such as `[ nil ]`, cause they still fail #any? test.

Comment: `tap{|a| a.delete([])`: maybe better just `reject(&:empty?)`.

Comment: You are right. That would be even prettier. Will you please edit my answer to show your additional option?

Comment: Good answer, but I would replace `.tap{ |a| a.delete( [] ) }` with `.select(&:any?)`

Comment: to avoid `nil` ouput: `reduce([], :&)`. And pretty please, don't use tap+delete like that, it's extremely convoluted.

Comment: @tokland `reduce([], :&)` does not work in this special case... (will always return `[]`).

Comment: @tokland: As for #reduce, on my version of irb it does not seem to need [] as the first parameter, which makes it all the more attractive to me. As for #tap issu, I find #tap to be an interesting new addition which I like to use. Is there any serious danger involved?

Comment: edit second option to
    [ a, b, c ].reject( &:empty? ).reduce( :& )

Answer (score 1):

```
[a, b, c].reject(&:blank?).reduce(:&)
```

Comment: And don't forget `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more concise means of doing this, but this should get you what you need.

```
def intersection(*arrays)
  # Reduce the list of arrays to only the ones with elements
  arrays = arrays.select(&:first)

  return [] if arrays.empty?

  # Grab the first array
  intersection = arrays.pop

  # Iterate over the arrays finding the intersection
  arrays.each do |array|
    intersection = intersection & array
  end

  # Return the resultant array
  intersection
end
```

**UPDATE**

I knew there was a method to apply an operator between all of the arrays elements, but for some reason I missed `reduce` when looking over the array docs. `reduce` is definitely the way to go:

```
arrays.reject(&:empty?).reduce(&:&)
```

Comment: Firstly, operators need not ampersand `&:&`, `:&` is enough. Secondly, you obviously could not encounter #reduce in Array documentation, as it is Enumerable mixin method, and thus available for all collections, and not just arrays. I commend you for your efforts.

Comment: @boris-stitnicky Huh, you only need `:&`? I wasn't aware of that. Is that a 1.9.x change, or has that always been the case?

Comment: I think it came in 1.9.x. For example, to sum numbers from 1 to 10 you can now write `[ *1..10 ].reduce( :+ )`.