# Is #tap method in Ruby dangerous?

Tags: ruby, piping

How does `tap` method work concurrencywise? Do I have to fear that if I do:

```
some_object.tap { |o|
  # time-consuming operation 1
}.tap { |o|
  # time-consuming operation 2
}
```

that, in the present or future, Ruby will try to do these operations concurrently? You know, `#tap` sounds dangerous.

Is it guaranteed that the `#tap` block executes in sequence (unless, of course, one does something unusual inside the block)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tap does not execute the block concurrently, but in sequence. So you do not have to worry about concurrency issues because there are no concurrency issues.

Here's the source of `tap`:

```
VALUE
rb_obj_tap(VALUE obj)
{
    rb_yield(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

So you can see that first it calls the block (`yield`), and only after that it returns the original object. There is no concurrency present.

Comment: Just that you know why I'm asking, because I happened to use #tap in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093430/how-do-i-find-intersection-of-3-arrays-while-ignoring-empty-arrays) and there was some booing over that, so I wanted to make doubly sure I'm not presenting a bad answer.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Ok I see. Well let's say you used `tap` in an unconventional way in that answer. Its original purpose was to "monitor" or "spy" on data (tap into the data) in long method call chains. But other than that there was nothing inherently wrong with your answer, but some of the other alternatives in the answer were more compact and to the point. I.e. basically try not to confuse the reader when you code too much, even though it works :)

Comment: Thanks. It was my fault that `delete` method came to my mind before `reject`, and then I just patched up the return value with `tap`.

Answer (score 5):

You have nothing to worry about.

Ruby execution will be sequential unless you do something to expressly make it parallel (e.g. creating threads).

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear.